# Publishing data in a data warehouse

Tags: architecture, metadata, data-warehouse, etl

Are there best practices or well known methods for publishing/announcing (via metadata etc) what data has been loaded, verified and is currently available for reporting in a data warehouse?

I've seen several in-house systems for doing this - some pretty fragile.

Are there some well-known concepts or good search terms I could look for?

Comment: Hm, in my opinion your question is way too broad for SO. What exactly do you want to achieve? Of course there are a number of ETL tools and products out there...

Comment: I realize the question is high level. However, I am not asking about the entire ETL process or ETL tools. I am specifically interested in what happens at the very end - once ETL has been successfully completed and verified. I am wondering if there are any standard concepts concerning how to inform end-users that data is ready to use in a way that is robust and maintainable. Is this part of the process always a roll-your-own affair?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for here, but what exactly are the users waiting for?

If it's for the system to be available again after a well-defined and consistent daily ETL process runs, then it's easy to send an email, re-enable your reporting application, update a status icon on your intranet site etc.

On the other hand, if they are waiting for a very specific data set ("is the Q4 sales data for the widget division in the south-east Asia region available yet?") then things are much more difficult because everyone is interested in something different. It's not even really a technical decision because knowing when source data is complete and correct is a business question that may have a different answer for each source system or data set. In our environment, daily reports are fully automated but monthly or yearly ones are not, mostly because there are often inconsistent events or processes that mean we still need a human being to confirm that the reports can be run.

I'm sure you could use metadata to build some kind of dashboard that shows when certain data was loaded, but it would be extremely specific to your situation and your users so I don't know if there's any general solution or pattern. I imagine it would be very dependent on your business processes, reporting schema (for the metadata) and reporting tools.

Comment: Thank you. That is actually a helpful. My experience has been no general solutions or patterns have been followed in the projects I have been involved with. The design of metadata and data-ready notifications have been very ad-hoc. It may be that this is an area that is too variable for best practices. However, it seems unusual that I have failed to find even some high-level discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the BI tool you are using on top of your warehouse and marts. IBM Cognos for example gives you a number of methods for users to find out about new data. This includes:-

1. Triggers that can be fired at the end of ETL processes that cause scheduled reports within Cognos to run.
2. Watch functionality that can be associated with specific reports and even cells within reports so that if new versions of report outputs are saved, or a cell value changes within a user defined range, that user can be informed.
3. Event notification functionality (event studio).

Item 2 is especially useful, because it enables users to start reporting by exception, rather than on a schedule. They can let the system tell them when they need to pay attention to something, rather than having a set of reports or queries they run on a rote schedule looking for changes.