# Enterprise integration via a data warehouse, or via messages?

Tags: service, architecture, integration, data-warehouse, servicebus

Imagine a large organisation with many applications.  The applications are not currently integrated to any great extent.  There is a new and empty enterprise data warehouse, and it would store all data in a canonical format.  The first step is to set up the warehouse and seed it with data from the applications.

I am looking for pros and cons between the following two enterprise integration patterns:

1) Using a combination of integration tools, setup batching to extract transform and load data on a periodic interval into the warehouse.  Then, as part of the process, integrate the data from the warehouse to the required applications.

2) Using a combination of integration tools, detect changes real-time, or in batch and publish them to a service bus (in canonical format). Then, for each required application, subscribe to the messages to integrate them.  The data warehouse is another subscriber to the same messages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One aspect that is hard to get right with integration-via-messages is periodic datasets.

Say you have a table in your data warehouse (DW) that contains data partitioned by day. If an ETL job loads that table, you can be sure that if the load job is finished, the respective dataset is complete (unless there's a bug in the job).

Messaging systems, on the other hand, usually don't provide guarantees of timely delivery. So you might get 90% of messages for a particular day by midnight, 8% within the next hour, and the remaining 2% within the next 6 hours (and a few messages might never arrive). In this situation, if you have a job that depends on this data, how can you know that the dataset is ready? You can set an arbitrary cutoff time (e.g. 1 hour past midnight) based on previous experience, SLAs, or some other criteria, when you consider the dataset complete, but that will by design be an approximation. You will also need some means to detect missing data (because of lost messages) and re-request it from the source.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9063578/843660) talks about similar problems.

Another issue is backfills. Imagine your source sends a backdated message, for example to correct some previously-sent one that belongs to a dataset in the past. Presumably, any consumers of that dataset need to be notified of the change and recompute their results. However, without some additional logic in the DW they might not know about it. With the ETL approach, since you already have dependencies between jobs, if you rerun some job with a backfill date, its dependencies will run automatically, or at least it'll be explicitly known that some consumers are affected.

With these caveats in mind, the messaging approach has some great advantages:

- all your systems will be integrated using a uniform approach
- the propagation time for your data will potentially be much lower
- you won't have to fix ETL jobs that exploded because the data volume has grown past their ability to scale
- you won't get SLA violations because your ETL jobs timed out

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about both [ETL Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) and [Mediation (intra-communication) design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation). I don't know why have to choose between them, in my current project we combine them.

The *ETL solution* is implemented *as Layer* responsible for management of the Data integration (via [Orchestrator module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestration_(computing))). It a single entry point and part of the [Pipes and filters design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568100.aspx)
concept that we rely on. It's able to perform a variety of tasks of varying complexity on the information that it processes.

On the other hand the *Mediation* as [EAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration) system acts as "broker" between multiple applications. Whenever an interesting event occurs in an application (for instance, new information is created or a new transaction completed) an integration module in the EAI system is notified. The module then propagates the changes to other relevant applications.

So as bottom line I can't give you *pros & cons* for both, since to me they are a good solution together and their use is dependent on your goals, design etc.. But from your description it's seems to me that is similar to what I've suggested.